# install module manually in yii2_advanced

Tags: module, yii2, composer-php, content-management-system, yii2-advanced-app

I downloaded Yeesoft CMS and now I want to add another module to this CMS without COMPOSER but its very complex and not working, I caught and very confuse to add or install module manually

These are my requests:

1. download this cms from https://yee-soft.com/installing
   then explain to me how could add a new module to this CMS?
2. could I add these modules to new Yii2 Advanced Project Manually without COMPOSER?

I read many topics to install manually module to yii2 without composer but it's not working on this CMS.

Comment: Why do you insist to not use composer?

Comment: because composer just used for module set it as Repository but i want learn how could i attach these module to another program and write new module and add it to this CMS

Comment: Well, if composer does the job, why not give it a chance?

Comment: i am so sorry because you don't pay attention to my question ! i said i want edit modules and add it manually but when you used composer you can't set your Second Version of module set to get because you don't have access to update repository and bela bela bela...